# slackclient OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files

Tags: python, linux, slack, urllib3, eoserror

I add slackclient on my app to get regular notification.
The app is executed on AWS Linux and in a docker container (FROM python:3.6.6-stretch).

Whenever I tried to execute it over about 1000 loops but the process failed 
 just after 1000 loops and I got the following errors.

I already checked other cases on stackoverflow but it doesn't work for me. Hope that I can get some insight from the answer of yours. I personally want to know why this happens and solve the core problems, not just detour it.

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 321, in ssl_wrap_socket
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 344, in connect
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 323, in ssl_wrap_socket
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 24] Too many open files

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='slack.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/chat.update (Caused by SSLError(OSError(24, 'Too many open files'),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/scraping/notify.py", line 50, in update
  File "/home/scraping/notify.py", line 70, in _api_call
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slackclient/client.py", line 184, in api_call
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slackclient/server.py", line 349, in api_call
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slackclient/slackrequest.py", line 84, in do
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slackclient/slackrequest.py", line 116, in post_http_request
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 116, in post
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='slack.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/chat.update (Caused by SSLError(OSError(24, 'Too many open files'),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 57, in create_connection
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 745, in getaddrinfo
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 343, in _make_request
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 839, in _validate_conn
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 301, in connect
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7ff2d9158048>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 24] Too many open files

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='slack.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/chat.postMessage (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7ff2d9158048>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 24] Too many open files',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 33, in <module>
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 127, in Fire
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 366, in _Fire
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fire/core.py", line 542, in _CallCallable
  File "main.py", line 29, in fasten
  File "/home/scraping/tasks/apps_info.py", line 199, in fasten
  File "/home/scraping/pipe.py", line 144, in _notify
  File "/home/scraping/notify.py", line 53, in update
  File "/home/scraping/notify.py", line 46, in resend
  File "/home/scraping/notify.py", line 70, in _api_call
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slackclient/client.py", line 184, in api_call
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slackclient/server.py", line 349, in api_call
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slackclient/slackrequest.py", line 84, in do
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/slackclient/slackrequest.py", line 116, in post_http_request
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 116, in post
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 60, in request
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
  File "/root/.local/share/virtualenvs/home-oTyxYuqD/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='slack.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/chat.postMessage (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7ff2d9158048>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 24] Too many open files',))
```

**SlackClient Part**

```
import errno
import time
import urllib3
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List, Text

import requests
from slackclient import SlackClient

import config
from .utils import get_utc_date


class SlackHelper:
    def __init__(self):
        self._date_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S"
        self._sc = SlackClient(config.SLACK_TOKEN)
        self._channel = config.SLACK_CHANNEL
        self._user_name = config.SLACK_USERNAME
        self._icon_emoji = config.SLACK_MSG_EMOJI
        self._ts = None
        self._ch_encoded = None
        self._created_at = get_utc_date(_format=self._date_format)

    def send(self, *args, **kw):
        return self._api_call(*args, **kw)

    def resend(self, resend_cnt: int = 0, *args, **kw):
        try:
            self._ts = None
            kw['method'] = 'chat.postMessage'
        except (urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError,
                urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError,
                requests.exceptions.ConnectionError) as err:
            if resend_cnt < 5:
                time.sleep(60)
                resend_cnt += 1
                self.resend(resend_cnt, *args, **kw)
            raise err
        return self._api_call(*args, **kw)

    def update(self, *args, **kw):
        try:
            return self._api_call(*args, **kw)
        except (requests.exceptions.ConnectionError,
                requests.exceptions.SSLError):
            self.resend(*args, **kw)
        except OSError as err:
            if err.errno == errno.EMFILE:
                return self.resend(*args, **kw)
            raise err

    def _api_call(self, title_prefix: Text, msg: Text,
                alarm: Text = 'good', method: Text = 'chat.postMessage'):
        attachments = self._get_attachments(title_prefix, msg, alarm)
        response = self._sc.api_call(
            method=method,
            channel=(
                self._ch_encoded if method == 'chat.update'
                else self._channel),
            attachments=[attachments],
            username=self._user_name,
            icon_emoji=self._icon_emoji,
            ts=self._ts if method == 'chat.update' else None)

        if self._check_retry(response):
            delay = int(response["headers"]["Retry-After"])
            time.sleep(delay)
            return self._api_call(title_prefix, msg, alarm, method)
        if response["ok"]:
            if not self._ts:
                self._ts = response.get('ts')
            self._ch_encoded = response.get('channel')
        return response.get('ok', True)

    @staticmethod
    def _check_retry(response):
        if response["ok"] is False:
            if response["headers"].get("Retry-After", False):
                delay = int(response["headers"]["Retry-After"])
                if delay < 60:
                    return True
        return False

    def _get_attachments(self, title_prefix, msg, alarm):
        now = get_utc_date(_format=self._date_format)
        return {
            "title": f"Created : {self._created_at}\n{title_prefix} : {now}",
            "text": msg,
            "mrkdwn_in": ["text"],
            "color": f"{alarm}"
        }
```

**ENV**

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 15698
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65535
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 15698
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to [run docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) container with `--ulimit` param

```
docker run -d --ulimit nofile=98304:98304 ...
```

Comment: I'll try but maybe that's not the case I guess. The container  is working well on local for over 1500 loops.

Comment: Oh 'ulimit -a' in the container shows open file 1024, but should I increase it? Is there anyway to find the reason why there's so many opened files? As I think, if there's so many open files like the above, it is caused by some kind of leaking so it would be more programmatically preferable to close the opened ones, not just increase the pool.